# How should the CV for the application of a pure math PhD applicant be structured?

Tags: phd, application, cv

I currently have four sections:

1. Education
2. Academic and research experiences
3. Honors and Awards
4. Work and Volunteer Experience

I have the following questions:

1. Should I include a section which gives a detailed account for the advanced math courses I have taken?
2. Should I elaborate on 3 and 4, or do I just list my awards and experience in those sections without explaining anything?
3. Should I include my research interest and standardized test scores in my CV?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a "detailed account" is necessary for anything that's a standard part of the math curriculum: a simple list would suffice. (Note that this would also apply to any other discipline with a "standard" curriculum, such as chemistry or physics!)

I would not include research interest and test scores, as they may be "restrictive" and turn off potential readers. (Test scores, if needed, must be provided in a more official way than just a CV listing, so you might as well leave it off.)

As for honors and awards and experience, I'd include specific information if it is relevant to your career aims; otherwise, a simple listing suffices.

Comment: Not even for PhD courses I have taken?

Comment: For PhD courses taken, this will likely be clear from your college transcript(s) and should be mentioned in at least one of your letters of recommendation. You can also mention the courses in your statement of interest (or cover letter, or personal statement, or whatever it's now called), which I did when I applied to math PhD programs in the 1980s. FWIW, I didn't make a CV (things may have been different then), but if I had, I would have had almost nothing to put for #2 (reading courses?), #3 (Putnam exam rank?), and #4 (fast food, restaurant cook, paper grader, data entry, farm work, etc.?).